# Flutter's PhotoManagergetAssetPathList doesn't show the last saved image when trying to display it

Tags: flutter, gallery, photo

I am developing a Flutter application.
After capturing the image using the camera package, the image was saved with GallerySaver.saveImage in the gallery_saver package.
I waited for GallerySaver.saveImage to finish processing, and on the next screen, I tried to view the image in the photo_manager package, but the image that should have been saved just before was not displayed.

When I open the OS standard photo app, the earlier image is saved, and when I restart the app, the image is displayed correctly, as well as the earlier image.

I have no idea what is causing this.
Is it an OS specification that images cannot be retrieved without restarting the app?